# OpenCL kernel very slow to execute, am I doing anything wrong?

Tags: opencl

I have written a Simple Moving average filter for Open CL and it is executing 2 to 3 orders of magnitude slower than on the CPU.

The simple moving average filter is a serial operation and I am executing with `cl::NDRange(1)` in the call to `enqueueNDRangeKernel()`.

The reason I am hoping to do this operation on the GPU rather than on the CPU is because ahead of this kernel there is some parallel processing of large arrays, which is working well, and after the moving average filter I only need about 1 in 100 of the samples so I can significantly reduce the amount of data I copy from the GPU back to the host, and hence speed up the operation.

I was hoping the GPU would not necessarily beat the CPU but be no more than a few x slower than it, which I would make up for in the reduced data transfer.

My kernel:

```
__kernel void SingleMovingAverage(__global double* InputSamples, 
                                  __global double* FilteredSamples, 
                  __global double* CircularBuffer,
                  double RunningTotal
                 )
{
    int CircularBufferPointerCtr = 0;   
    
    for(int sampleCtr = 0; sampleCtr < 262144; sampleCtr++)
    {
        RunningTotal += InputSamples[sampleCtr];
        RunningTotal -= CircularBuffer[CircularBufferPointerCtr];
        FilteredSamples[sampleCtr] = RunningTotal;
        
        CircularBuffer[CircularBufferPointerCtr] = InputSamples[sampleCtr];
        
        CircularBufferPointerCtr++;
        CircularBufferPointerCtr &= 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Maybe GPUs are this much slower when executing single serial tasks?

Comment: 2 or 3x slower for a single threaded application is pretty good. Often it would be much worse. GPUs aren't designed to run single threaded code well. They typically run at much lower frequencies and have much more limited instruction sets than x86_64 CPUs. FP64 performance varies widely across GPUs too.

Answer (score 1):

Except for embarrassingly parallel (lots of identical, dependency-free operations on data in a convenient vector format), you'll always need to expect to make some modifications to the algorithm to have *any* chance of making it perform well on a GPU.

Sure, the trivial implementation of a moving average algorithm is strictly serial, but that doesn't mean it's impossible to parallelise. One thing you need to let go of from the world of optimising serial code is that it's perfectly normal to *increase* the total operation count in order to *decrease* the number of sequentially dependent operations. The other thing is that code complexity usually goes up.

It looks like you're taking 262144 (`N`) input samples (`I`) and generating 262144 (`N`) filtered outputs (`F`), where each output is the sum of the window of the last 256 (`M`) samples up to and including the current input.

An idea for parallelising this off the top of my head would be to use chunking, and approach the problem in multiple passes. Essentially, we'll be making the following observations:

We are after `F[j] = sum(I[j-255..j])`, `F[255] = sum(I[0..255])`, `F[256] = sum(I[1..256])`, etc. (With suitable boundary conditions such that negative indices into `I` yield zeros.) This can be rewritten as:

- `T[j] = sum(I[j*32..j*32+31])` (`T[0] = sum(I[0..31])`, `T[1] = sum(I[32..63])` etc.
- `F[255] = sum(T[0..7]) = T[0] + sum(T[1..7])` or
  `F[255] = sum(I[0..31]) + sum(T[1..7])`
- `F[256] = sum(I[1..31]) + sum(T[1..7]) + sum(I[0..0])`
- `F[257] = sum(I[2..31]) + sum(T[1..7]) + sum(I[0..1])`
- etc.

We can re-use these `sum(T[1..7])` expressions! And the bit at the front (`sum(I[2..31])` etc.) is a suffix sum, while the bit at the back (`sum(I[0..0])`) is a prefix sum.

1. Choose a chunk size (`C`) which is a suitably smaller pow2 factor of the window size. Using a square root of problem size (sqrt(M) = 16) is frequently convenient to implement and usually theoretically optimal, but can lock you into being difficult to optimise or modify your window size in this case, and not be optimal in practice; but it's probably good enough for a proof of concept.
2. Allocate a temporary buffer `T` to hold `N/C` sums. You'll be passing this between kernels.
3. Submit a first kernel with `N` work items and a group size of `C`. This performs a parallel reduction sum on groups of 16 adjacent input samples. `InputSamples[0..C-1] -> T[0]`, `InputSamples[C..2*C-1]` -> `T[1]`, etc.
4. Submit a second kernel, again with `N` work items and a group size of `C`.

   - First, perform a parallel sum of the `M/C-1` chunks of `T` shared by *all* outputs generated by the thread group, let's call the result `Ts`.
   - Perform a parallel suffix sum reduction `S` of the `C` input samples immediately prior to the first shared `T`. Perform a parallel *prefix* sum reduction `P` of the `C` input values following the last shared `T`.
   - Each filtered output value is `S[i] + Ts + P[i]`.

The serial algorithm uses a linearly scaling number of operations. (O(`N`))

The parallel algorithm has a computational complexity of roughly `O(N * (3*log(C) + log(M/C))`, but with a smaller constant factor, and scaling to up to `N` execution units, the *dependent* operations and therefore time complexity are around `O(3*log(C) + log(M/C))`. You probably won't have 262144 cores, and in practice the whole thing won't scale quite so efficiently, but you should still see a big jump in performance.

One downside of this algorithm is that we're reading the whole input array in 2 different kernels, which means more memory bandwidth used. Profiling and performance counters will tell you if this is enough of a problem to starve the ALUs on your target hardware. (If your data size really is only 2MB, it should fit in cache anyway though.

Also, on consumer GPU hardware, arithmetic on `double`s will struggle to keep up with available memory bandwidth - that's the other thing, unless you're targeting server/workstation GPUs, consider whether you really need `double`s or if you could perhaps use `float`s or 64-bit fixed-point types.